# On the interpretation of the limsup of a sequence of events

Tags: measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

In the context of understanding Borel-Cantelli lemmas, I have come across the expression for a sequence of events $\{E_n\}$:

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k\geq n}^\infty E_k$$

following [Wikipedia notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Statement%20of%20lemma%20for%20probability%20spaces). This is verbalized as:

1. Limit supremum of the sequence of events when $n\rightarrow\infty$: $\limsup\limits_{\small n\rightarrow\infty}E_n$.
2. The event that occurs "infinitely often": $\{E_n \,\text{i.o.}\}$ or the set that belongs to "infinitely many" $E_n$'s.

The explanation is that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{k\geq n}^\infty E_k$ is the event that *at least one* of the $E_n,E_{n+1},E_{n+2,\cdots}$ events occurs.

The question is about the meaning of $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty $ in front.

The way I look at it is that it would play the role of excluding every $\{E_n\}$ imaginable with $n\in\mathbb N$. For instance, when $n=1$, the union part of the expression would render: $\{E_1,E_2,E_3,\cdots\}$; and when $n=2$, this same union operation would yield: $\{E_2,E_3,\cdots\}$. So the intersection in front of the expression would eliminate $\{E_1\}$ and leave the rest. Next would come the intersection with $\{E_3,E_4,\cdots\}$, excluding $\{E_2\}$. Doing this exercise at infinity would manage to exclude every single $\{E_n\}$.

Is this what the intersection/union operation is supposed to do: "clip" out every single set? My understanding is that this is not the case, and that we want to end up with a "tail" of events after point $k$.

What is the correct interpretation, and what is the mistake I am making?

NOTE to self: It is not about the "clipped out" sets at the beginning, but rather about the tail events. The union part indicates that any of the events after event $n$ occurs, defining the "$n$-th tail event." The intersection is defines the event that all the $n$-th tail events occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The union, as you say, expresses that at least one of the events after the index $n$ occurs. The intersection expresses that this is true for **all** $n$. Hence no matter how 'far' you go in the sequence, there will be an event in the sequence even 'further', that occurs. In other words, this precisely means that infinitely many of them occur.

Comment: Thank you. Is my mistake, then, that I am doing "pairwise" intersections between infinitely long strings of events, when the intersection symbol is less "literal"... more abstract or conceptual?

Comment: I'm not sure what counts as abstract, but yes, I would not approach an infinite intersection 'one-by-one'. Simply use the fact that the intersection of events (finite or infinitely many of them) is the event where all of them happens.